The memory consumed by WSO2 APIM increases over time
I have an instance of WSO2 APIM version 4.2.0 installed on an Oracle Linux 8 server which has 16gb of ram. The problem noticed is that the more time passes, the more the consumption of physical memory increases even if no request is sent to wso2 APIM. This behavior manages to consume all the available memory to the point of making wso2 APIM unavailable and even the server on which it is installed.
What could be the reasons for this behavior and how can I resolve it please?
I tried to reinstall the product, but nothing changed, the same behavior returns

You could get a heap dump and analyze what consumes the memory. It's hard to provide an answer without more details about the Deployment and the APIs deployed.
